# Reading XML into SQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server, xml, rdbms

I am reading the xml and writing it into sql tables

Want to insert below xml into table

> ```
> Declare @MainXml XML =
> '<Parent>
>   <Root>
>       <Admin>admin1</Admin>
>       <Data number="1">
>         <Type value="100"></Type>
>         <Type value="200"></Type>
>      </Data>        
>   </Root>
>  <Root>
>      <Admin>admin2</Admin>
>      <Data number="1">
>        <Type value="300"></Type>
>        <Type value="400"></Type>
>      </Data>
>  </Root>
> </Parent>'
> ```
>
> I am trying to insert into table like this
>
> ```
> Insert Into Table1(col1,col2)
>   SELECT
>    A.RT.value('Admin[1]','varchar(max)'),
>    B.DT.value('@value','varchar(max)')
>    FROM @MainXml.nodes('Parent/Root') as A(RT)
> ```
>
> cross apply A.RT.nodes('Data/Type') as B(DT)

It will work fine on above xml.

If section  is removed it wont work.

Why my query is not work for

> ```
> Declare @MainXml XML =
> '<Parent>
>   <Root>
>       <Admin>admin1</Admin>     
>   </Root>
>  <Root>
>      <Admin>admin2</Admin>
>  </Root>
> </Parent>'
> ```

Section  in my XML may or may not be there. so how to handle such xml.

If no data, want to enter null to it.

Please suggest me.

Comment: Please fix your tags to reflect the RDBMS you are using (MySQL or MS SQL-Server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

EDIT: Oh I just realised, that there are more than one Type-nodes. Wait a little...

OK, you did perfectly well, just change CROSS APPLY to OUTER APPLY...

HTH